# How do I add \Huge to an image source in jQue

Tags: jquery

http://jsbin.com/owepu3/edit

I'm using mimeTex to generate LaTex images using a cgi script, and I want to add a dynamic size. However, when the source file gets generated, it drops the "\" from "\Huge".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`\` is used to escape characters in Javascript.

Try using `\\Huge` instead.

Comment: I tried this, but sometimes it accepts the \ and print "\\huge" as part of the laTex expression

Comment: ok, now I'm confused. Isn't this what you want? I may has misunderstood. What exactly is the URL that you want the image src to be?